# iPhone - Make UITableViewCells appear on view load before NSURLConnection completes

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I am trying to create a loose version of LazyTabelImages using storyboard and JSON. in ViewDidLoad on my main TableViewController, I start an NSURLConnection to get the JSON data, but my cells do not load until after the connection is completed. I want the same behavior that LazyTableImages has, where the cells load as blanks, but then have the information filled in (reload the table data). I can duplicate this if I do not use storyboard, as LazyTables does not use storyboard, but that is not an option.

I have looked through LazyTableImages to try to find the solution, but storyboard make a big difference (to me anyway).

Is there a simple way to get the cells to load as blanks? For example, if the device has no internet, I still want my TableView to show up, and I will put a custom message in the cell.

Code:

The part of my viewDidLoad where I initialize the connection....

```
NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
    self.dataConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlrequest delegate:self];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

connectionDidFinnishLoading...

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //ListData below is an array that my data received (JSON) is loaded into. It is then passed to getTableData.
    self.dataConnection = nil;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getTableData:) withObject:ListData waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

getTableData...

```
-(void)getTableData:(NSData *)jsonData
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    arrayEntries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayEntries.count; x++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [arrayEntries objectAtIndex:x];

        //ARecord is a class just like in LazyTableImages that creates objects to keep the icons/data together. The ARecords are loaded into the TableView
        ARecord *arecord = [[ARecord alloc] init];

        NSString *title = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *subt = [dic objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
        NSString *url = [dic objectForKey:@"image_URL"];
        arecord.Icon = nil;
        arecord.URL = url;
        arecord.Name = title;
        arecord.title = subt;

        //this is where I load an array full of the arecord objects.
        [array addObject:arecord];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: did you call network on main thread? if that, the networking block UI thread.

Comment: I have tried using GCD to move it off the main thread, but then I just get a white screen because the table never loads. There is a GCD call in the NURLConnection, to handle the JSON parsing on different threads.

Comment: Note that your NSURLConnection is (should) already be asynchronous. Moving it to a background thread is probably a bad idea. As Quinn says, where networking is concerned "Threads Are Evil™".

Comment: I remember that too, but no matter how I cut it; either moving the NSURLConnection to a background thread, or moving the parsing to a background thread, the cells don't load until the NSURLConnection is complete. I need to move that initial download out of the UIs way.

Comment: you have used asyn newworking, so there is no need to use the gcd.

Comment: How do I get the TableViewCells to appear before the JSON is finished loading? do I need to create cells in viewDidLoad?

Comment: If your cells aren't displaying until after your JSON loads, either: Your networking call to load the JSON isn't really asynchronous. In which case, threading is not the answer. You must make it async. Or parsing the loaded JSON is so expensive that it's tying up the main thread. In which case, something is probably crazy wrong around your JSON parser. It shouldn't be doing anything long enough to hang the interface. Profile to find the true culprit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: With fast internet it is fine, what is causing the delay is a slow internet connection. If the device has no internet, the NSURLConnection never gets data, and I can't find a way to load the Table in the NSURLConnection error handling. I was trying to load the TableView in viewDidLoad, so that there would be some sign of UI, and then if NSURLConnection fails, I would populate the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar. In viewDidLoad: I set the array for table data to a few objects of [NSNull null] for however many blank rows I want to show while the data is downloading. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: I check if [self.arrayOfTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] = [NSNull null]. If so return a "blank" cell, otherwise load the cell with ARRecrod data.
Then when the URL completes, replace the array of NSNulls with array of your ARRecords.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with two objects. First, I have an image fetcher class that downloads data asynchronously and notifies a delegate when it's complete. Then I have an image view class that implements the fetcher's delegate methods. So something like:

```
@implementation AsyncImageFetcher
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL andDelegate:(id<SomeProtocol>)aDelegate{

  //...

  NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
  //Note that NSURLConnection retains its delegate until the connection
  //terminates! See comments in MyImageView below.
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

  //...
}

//Implement standard connection delegates here. The important part is:
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

  // ...

  UIImage *anImage = [self decodeDownloadedDataIntoAnImage];
  if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(imageFetcher:didFetchImage:)]){
    [[self delegate] imageFetcher:self didFetchImage:anImage];
  }

  //...
}

@end
```

Then I subclass `UIImageView` or `UIView` or something (depending on how flexible you need to be) to implement the delegate protocol and fire off the fetcher:

```
@implementation MyImageView

-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL andPlaceHolderImage:(UIImage *)aPlaceHolder{

  //...

  [self setImage:aPlaceHolder];

  //Note we don't assign this to an ivar or retain it or anything. 
  //That's ok because the NSURLConnection inside the fetcher actually 
  //retains the fetcher itself. So it will live until the connection 
  //terminates -- which is exactly what we want. Thus we disable 
  //CLANG's noisy warnings.
  #pragma clang diagnostic push
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
  [[AsyncImageFetcher alloc] initWithURL:aURL andDelegate:self];
  #pragma clang diagnostic pop

  return self;
}


-(void)imageFetcher:(MCMAsyncImageFetcher *)anImageFetcher didFetchImage:(UIImage *)anImage{
  [self setImage:anImage];
}

@end
```

In your specific case, you'd just set a `MyImageView` as your cell's `imageView` in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, passing reasonable values for its placeholder and URL, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added code to help eliminate any confusion. It just took a while to get only what I need out and edited correctly.

Comment: I tired it this way, but the way I am doing it now is the best for handling my initial JSON call. I get the images in a second class, this is just to get the fist bits of JSON that contains the URLS to get the images asynchronously later. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's the same for loading JSON async. Just, instead of `-decodingDowloadedDataIntoAnImage` you'd parse downloaded JSON data into objects. And instead of using an image as a delegate, you'd use (presumably) your table's controller so that it can reload the table with the new JSON data one's it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't see your code, I just give my suggestion here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        //add your connection code here
        //parse the json and store the data
        //

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //here to reload your table view again, 
            //since UI related method should run on main thread.

            [YOUR_TABLEVIEW reloadData];

        });

    });

    [YOUR_TABLEVIEW reloadData];
}
```

Note: Make sure your tableview in storyboard has connected to that in code! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking this was the approach I needed all along, but I still cant get it to work. I have added code to help eliminate confusion.

Comment: So I have tried it this way, and I just get hung up in the dispatch calls. Any other suggestions now that I have posted some code? Thanks

Comment: Be careful! It's almost always a mistake to do networking on a thread.